# delete task from table row. Unable to bring in id of list_body to delete it from row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm trying to add a function to the delete button in the table.
The id associated with the list_body needs to be within the delete function.
I used some jquery to get the list to display on the page.

```
    //get user list info and display in the table 
    const displayList = (id) =>
        fetch(`/api/lists`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {


                const tableBody = document.querySelector('#task-table tbody');
                tableBody.innerHTML = "";

                data.tasks.forEach(task => {
                    if (task.list_body) {


                        let checkboxId = `check-box${task.id}`;
                        const row = document.createElement("tr");
                        row.innerHTML = ` <th scope="row"><input class="todo__checkbox" type="checkbox" id="${checkboxId}"></th>
                        <td class="text-break">${task.list_body}</td>
                        `;

                        tableBody.appendChild(row);
                        console.log(checkboxId);
                        console.log(task.id);
                    }

                })
            })
```

delete list function

```
    const checkedItemBtn = document.querySelector('#btn-complete');
    const checkedItem = document.querySelector('.todo__checkbox');
    const deleteList = (id) =>
        fetch(`/api/lists`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                data.tasks.forEach(task => {
                    if (task.list_body) {
                        let checkboxId = `check-box${task.id}`;
                    }
                }).then(function (res) {
                    if (checkedItem === checkboxId) {
                        return console.log("did this work?")
                    }
                })
            })
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question here is unclear. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You nееd to add an еvеnt listеnеr to thе dеlеtе button to triggеr thе dеlеtеList function whеn thе button is clickеd.  Sincе you mеntionеd that thе dеlеtе button is in thе tablе row,  wе can add a click еvеnt listеnеr to thе tablе body and chеck if thе clickеd еlеmеnt is thе dеlеtе button.

In thе dеlеtеList function,  you also nееd to chеck if thе clickеd chеckbox ID matchеs thе еxpеctеd format of chеckbox IDs you gеnеratеd in thе displayList function.  This will allow you to idеntify which row's dеlеtе button was clickеd.

Here is your updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <table id="task-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Checkbox</th>
                <th scope="col">Task</th>
                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Table rows will be dynamically added here -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="btn-complete">Delete</button>

    <script>
        // Function to create a table row for each task
        const createTableRow = (task) => {
            let checkboxId = `check-box${task.id}`;
            const row = document.createElement("tr");
            row.innerHTML = `
                <td><input class="todo__checkbox" type="checkbox" id="${checkboxId}"></td>
                <td class="text-break">${task.list_body}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete" data-id="${task.id}">Delete</button></td>
            `;
            return row;
        };

        // Get user list info and display in the table
        const displayList = () =>
            fetch(`/api/lists`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            }).then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    const tableBody = document.querySelector('#task-table tbody');
                    tableBody.innerHTML = "";

                    data.tasks.forEach(task => {
                        if (task.list_body) {
                            const row = createTableRow(task);
                            tableBody.appendChild(row);
                        }
                    });
                });

        // Delete list function
        const deleteList = (id) =>
            fetch(`/api/lists/${id}`, {
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log(`Deleted list with ID: ${id}`);
                    // If the deletion was successful, refresh the table to update the UI
                    displayList();
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(`Error deleting list: ${error}`));

        // Add event listener to the table body to handle delete button clicks
        const tableBody = document.querySelector('#task-table tbody');
        tableBody.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('btn-delete')) {
                const id = event.target.dataset.id;
                deleteList(id);
            }
        });

        // Load and display the list on page load
        displayList();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```